# insert row in existing table

Tags: jquery, html

[image]

I'm having problem inserting content into already existing table. Everything works fine excepts the insertion. The insertion point is a span beneath the thead element and above the php for loop that generates the table rows seen in the picure. The content that is to be inserted is properly embedded inside a table row and table data's. Is it even possible to insert rows dynamically after the table is created?

edit:

```
            <table class="table table-hover" id="revolver">
                    <thead>
                        <td id="profile-message-indicator"></td>
                        <td id="profile-message-space">Message</td>
                        <td id="profile-message-name-space">To</td>
                        <td>Date/Time</td>
                    </thead>

                    <span id="insert-sent-message">


                    </span>

                    <?php if(isset($message_list[1][0]['message_state'])){?>

                    <?php for($i = 0; $i < $array_length_send; $i++){ ?>

                    <tr>

                        <?php if(strlen($message_list[1][$i]['message']) >= 54){?>

                            <td id="profile-message-indicator">

                                <a href="" class="extend-message" data-messageid="<?php echo $message_list[1][$i]['message_id']; ?>"><strong class="profile-extend-message">+</strong></a>

                            </td>

                            <td class="table-data-string">

                            <span id="substring-message<?php echo $message_list[1][$i]['message_id']; ?>">

                                <p class="comments-layout"><?php echo substr($message_list[1][$i]['message'], 0, 54); ?>...</p>


                            </span>

                        <?php } else { ?>

                            <td></td>

                            <td class="table-data-string">

                            <span id="substring-message<?php echo $message_list[1][$i]['message_id']; ?>">

                                <p class="comments-layout"><?php echo $message_list[1][$i]['message']; ?></p>

                            </span>

                        <?php }?>

                            <span class="complete-message" id="complete-message<?php echo $message_list[1][$i]['message_id']; ?>">

                                <p class="comments-layout"><?php echo $message_list[1][$i]['message']; ?></p>

                            </span>

                        </td>

                        <td>

                            <a href="" class="goto-author" data-author="<?php echo $message_list[1][$i]['author']; ?>"><?php echo $message_list[1][$i]['recip']; ?></a>

                        </td>

                        <td>

                            <p><?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($message_list[1][$i]['message_timestamp'])); ?></p>

                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <?php }} else {?>

                        <!-- EMPTY NO MESSAGES -->

                    <?php  }?>
                </table>
```

HTML template being inserted:

```
<tr>

<?php if(strlen($reply) >= 54){ ?>

    <td id="profile-message-indicator">

        <a href="" class="extend-message" data-messageid="<?php echo $message_id[0]?>"><strong class="profile-extend-message">+</strong></a>

    </td>

    <td class="table-data-string">

        <span id="substring-message<?php echo $message_id[0]; ?>">

            <p class="comments-layout"><?php echo substr($reply, 0, 54); ?>...</p>

        </span>

<?php } else { ?>

    <td>
    </td>

    <td class="table-data-string">

        <span id="substring-message<?php echo $message_id[0]; ?>">

            <p class="comments-layout"><?php echo $reply;?></p>


        </span>
<?php }?>

    <span class="complete-message-reply" id="complete-message<?php echo $message_id[0]; ?>">

        <p class="comments-layout"><?php echo $reply;?></p>

    </span>

</td>

<td>

    <a href="" class="goto-author" data-author="<?php echo $recipient; ?>"><?php echo $recipient; ?></a>

</td>

<td>
    <?php echo $today; ?>
</td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
    $(document).on('click','.submit-message-reply',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var messageid = $(this).data('messageid');
    var reply = $('#message-reply-container'+messageid).val();
    var recipient = $(this).data('recipient');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '?a=profile_message_reply',
        data: {
            "messageid" : messageid,
            "reply" : reply,
            "recipient" : recipient
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#message-reply-container'+messageid).val("");
            $('#insert-sent-message').append(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it is possible, show your code..

Comment: you have to inserted like this .append("<tr><td class=''>"+val+"</td></tr>");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `span` in between table rows, it makes your html invalid. Also wrap table cells in `thead` with `tr` for the same reason.

Then use `.after()` on table header row instead of `.append()` on the span.

```
$('#revolver tr:first').after(data);​
```

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sPC6g/).

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
$("#revolver").append("<tr><td class='table-data-string'>"+val+"</td></tr>");
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is yes - it is possible to insert rows tow a table after a table has been inserted.

You can do that by

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '?a=profile_message_reply',
    data: {
        "messageid" : messageid,
        "reply" : reply,
        "recipient" : recipient
    },
    success: function(data){
        var new_row = document.createElement("tr");

        var new_tds = {
            td_indicator: document.createElement("td"),
            td_space: document.createElement("td"),
            td_name_space: document.createElement("td"),
            td_date: document.createElement("td")
        };

        new_tds.td_indicator.addAttribute("class", "profile-message-indicator");
        new_tds.td_space.addAttribute("class", "profile-message-space");
        new_tds.td_name_space.addAttribute("class", "profile-message-name-space");
        new_tds.td_date.addAttribute("class", "profile-message-date");

        var td_texts = {
            td_indicator: document.createTextNode(response.indicator),
            td_space: document.createTextNode(response.space),
            td_name_space: document.createTextNode(response.name_space),
            td_date: document.createTextNode(response.date)
        };

        $.each(new_tds, function(key, value) {
            new_tds[key].appendChild(td_texts[key]);
            new_row.appendChild(new_tds[key]);
        });

        $("table#revolver").append(new_row);
    },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

All you would have to do on the server side is to json_encode the data array.